# Como pegar valor de um RadioButon para salvar em uma Classe

Tags: java

Preciso fazer uma tela em que o cliente tem várias opções de *radio buttons* para selecionar, aí tenho que pegar esse valores e setar em uma classe que tem o campo `valor`.

```
private String nota; /*quero salvar aqui*/

public String getNota() {
   return nota;
}

public void setNota(String nota){
    this.nota = nota;
}


private JRadioButton getRdbtnOtimo() {
        if (rdbtnOtimo == null) {
            rdbtnOtimo = new JRadioButton("\u00D3timo");
            rdbtnOtimo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (rdbtnOtimo.isSelected()) {
                        rdbtnPessimo.setSelected(false);
                        rdbtnNormal.setSelected(false);
                        rdbtnBom.setSelected(false);
                        rdbtnRuim.setSelected(false);
                        ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage();
                        cm.setNota("Ótimo");
                    }
                }
            });
            rdbtnOtimo.setBackground(new Color(248, 252, 255));
        }
        return rdbtnOtimo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua string nota já possui o valor do método setNota, qual seria o problema?
Para resgatar o que tem na variável nota você pode tentar usar assim:

```
// Exemplo:    
String notaNova = cm.getNota();
```